# Can I create a shopify webhook which trigger on authorized instead of paid?

Tags: shopify, webhooks

Can I create a shopify webhook which trigger once payment on an order have been authorized?

I can create one which trigger once an order have been paid, but I really need one which trigger once credit card payment on an order have been authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. It requires two webhooks instead of one

Create a webhook for `orders/create` and use `{ "fields" : ["id", "updated_at", "financial_status"] }` (something similar - https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/order) in the webhook. At the receiving end add a check if `financial_status` is `authorized` and proceed.

With everything else same create a new webhook for `orders/updated` so that whenever the payment is updated it gets triggered.

You may use additional fields as required.